# Why am I getting this 'no route matches' error on a link_to? I have the route defined! (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

so I have this code:

```
link_to 'text', :copy_job, :id => 1
```

which matches this route definition:

```
match 'hive_jobs/copy/:id' => 'hive_jobs#copy', :as => :copy_job
```

and if I browse to the page /hive_jobs/copy/1 it works

But the link_to throws the following exception:

```
No route matches {:action=>"copy", :controller=>"hive_jobs"}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `link_to 'text', copy_job_path(1)`

Comment: It seems silly that this doesn't work, it works for routes without required parameters. Any idea why?

Comment: Because your code had `:id => 1` as the third parameter to `link_to`, which is supposed to be your HTML options. So it was actually trying to do something like `<a href="/hive_jobs/copy" id="1">`.